# Test class which depends on Guice Provider<T>

Tags: java, mockito, guice, jukito

How to test a class which depends on `Provider<>`?
Please see the code below.

```
class ToTest {

    @Inject
    Provider<Processor> processorProvider;

    public buildData() {
        processorProvider.get().process();
    }

    class ProcessorProviderImpl implements Provider<Processor> {
        @Inject
        private Handler someHandler;

        public Processor get() {
            return new MyProcessor(somehandler)
        }
    }

    public static class TestModule extends JukitoModule {
        @Override
        protected void configureTest() {
            bind(Processor.class).toProvider(
                    ProcessorInstanceProviderImpl.class);
            bindMock(SubHandler.class).in(TestSingleton.class);
        }
    }

    class Handler {
        @Inject
        private SubHandler subHandler; // this is singleton instance
    }
}
```

So when I mock `subHandler` it doesn't work and when I run unit test I am getting a `NullPointerException` where `subHandler.handle()` is getting called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to use Guice and JMock together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044991/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-guice-and-jmock-together)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Providers.of() to initialize processorProvider with a provider of your collaborator instance.

https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/util/Providers.html

```
test = new ToTest();
test.processorProvider = Providers.of(processorMock);
```

Comment: Sorry i have rephrased my question. What if i dont want to mock instance provider, but a dependency of its dependency.

Comment: And why you don't want to mock a collaborator !?
You have to mock it, it's not a good idea to use the real object.
And if you want to mock a " a dependency of its dependency" maybe there is a bad design: you are violating the Law of Demeter
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter